# DacFx DeploymentPlanExecutor OnExecute not called

Tags: c#, deployment, dacpac, dac

I'm trying to program a custom `DeploymentPlanExecutor` using Microsofts DacFx 3.0 but the `OnExecute`-Method is never called.

- If I use an identical `DeploymentPlanModifier` instead, `OnExecute()` is called as expected.
- No matter whether I add the Executor, the Modifier, or both, the DAC actually is successfully deployed to the Database.
- The Executor seems to be recognized during the Deployment since `OnApplyDeploymentConfiguration()` is called

Unfortunately I wasn't able to find any examples that use an `DeploymentPlanExecutor` (only examples with `DeploymentPlanModifier`) and the documentation of DacFx does not help at all.

My question is, why is `OnExecute()` in the `DeploymentPlanExecutor` not called and how can I fix this?

The code for my `DeploymentPlanExecutor` and `DeploymentPlanExecutor`:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Deployment;

namespace DacTest
{
    // The executor that does not work as expected
    [ExportDeploymentPlanExecutor(ContributorId, "1.0.0.0")] 
    public class Executor : DeploymentPlanExecutor
    {
        public const string ContributorId = "DacTest.Executor";

        protected override void OnApplyDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentContributorContext context, ICollection<DeploymentContributorConfigurationStream> configurationStreams)
        {
            // Called
        }

        protected override void OnEstablishDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentContributorConfigurationSetup setup)
        {
            // Not called
        }

        protected override void OnExecute(DeploymentPlanContributorContext context)
        {
            // Not called!
        }
    }

   // The modifier that does work as expected
   [ExportDeploymentPlanModifier(ContributorId, "1.0.0.0")] 
    public class Modifier : DeploymentPlanModifier
    {
        public const string ContributorId = "DacTest.Modifier";

        protected override void OnApplyDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentContributorContext context, ICollection<DeploymentContributorConfigurationStream> configurationStreams)
        {
            // Called
        }

        protected override void OnEstablishDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentContributorConfigurationSetup setup)
        {
            // Not called
        }

        protected override void OnExecute(DeploymentPlanContributorContext context)
        {
            // Called!
        }
    }
}
```

The code calling the deployment (has to be in a different assembly):

```
using (DacPackage dacpac = DacPackage.Load(@"C:\Temp\dac.dacpac"))
{
    DacDeployOptions dacDeployOptions = new DacDeployOptions();
    dacDeployOptions.AdditionalDeploymentContributors = Executor.ContributorId; // + ";" + Modifier.ContributorId;

    DacServices dacServices = new DacServices(connectionString);
    dacServices.Deploy(dacpac, databaseName, true, dacDeployOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was, that you have to explicitly tell DacFx to use Executors. Modifiers are enabled by default though.

`dacDeployOptions.RunDeploymentPlanExecutors = true;`